# All @Before and @After scenario methods are getting called before a scenario execution

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a feature file with some scenarios in it, and I have step definitions (`.java` files) defined for all the scenarios. In each step definition, I have `@Before` (`beforeScenario`) and `@After` (`afterScenario`) functions. The problem is that before each scenario gets executed, all the defined `@Before` and `@After` methods in all the step definitions are getting called.

Is there a way where I could implement it such that only when a scenario is being executed, the `@Before` and `@After` scenario methods in that scenario's step definition file are being executed, not the methods in other step definitions.

Comment: You need to isolate those methods into its own class/group, looks like your preconditions do not apply to everything on that file. You can also play with a combination of `@BeforeClass`, `@Before`, `@AfterClass`, and `@After`, but it can get tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an default nature of before to run before each scenario but if you want a specific before to execute then do as below with tag 
You can use with tag name as below:

Feature File:

```
@First 
Scenario: This is First Scenario
 Given this is the first step
 When this is the second step
 Then this is the third step
```

Hook/step defination java file:

```
 @Before("@First")
    public void beforeFirst(){
        System.out.println("This will run only before the First Scenario");
    }
```

Above before will run for this scenario only, you can use same tag with other scenario in feature file where you want this before to invoke:

Source and for more details:

https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber/tagged-hooks-in-cucumber/